# Plotting unit circles in matlab and using the hold on to insert individual data points and plotting the intersection with circle

Tags: matlab

I was trying to produce the following figure:

[image]

as similar as possible. I was having difficulties because I wasn't sure how to plot the unit circle. How does one do that? I tried using the polar function but I couldn't then make it also plot the blue crosses and red crosses. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

**Edited answer**

Here is a part of the code:

```
% --- Plot everything on the same axes
hold on

% --- Plot the unit circle:

theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 360);
plot(cos(theta), sin(theta), 'k--');

% --- Plot the blue points

x = [0.2 0.4 0.4 0.8];
y = [0.4 0.2 0.8 0.4];
scatter(x, y, 'bs');

% --- Plot the red points:

x = [0.4 0.8];
y = [0.4 0.8];
scatter(x, y, 'ro');
```

There are still many modifications to do to get the final plots, but at least this is a starting point.

---

**Second edit**

To answer your question about the intersection of a line and a circle, you have to start with the maths behind. Line and circle are defined by the following equations:

```
y = a.x + b                % Cartesian definition of a line
(x-x0)² + (y-y0)² = r²     % Cartesian definition of a circle
```

If you combine the two, you realize that finding the intersection is similar to finding the solution of:

```
(a²+1).x² + 2(a(b-y0)-x0).x + x0²+(b-y0)²-r² = 0
```

*i.e.* the roots of a polynom. As this is a trinom, there are 3 possibilities: 0 solution (no intersection), 1 solution (line is tangent to the circle) and 2 solutions (line crossing the circle).

So, in practice you have to:

- Get the parameters `a`, `b`, `x0`, `y0` and `r` of your problem
- Find the roots of the polynom (for instance, with the function [`roots`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html))
- Decide what to do based on the number of roots.

Hope this helps,

Comment: sorry if this is very basic, but how do I plot exact points too? Like the blue and red points?

Comment: I want to mix lines in plot and scatter, not sure if that is possible

Comment: For sure it is possible. Just be sure to use `hold on` to overlay the different plots.

Comment: Last question to make this the perfect answer. Is there a way to find the intersection points of the unit circle and the line drawn in the diagram? (you've definitively help me a lot thnx!)

Comment: Yes, but which line ? Do you want an answer specific for this configuration or a general answer ?

Comment: Probably the general one includes the first one...so the general one (or both)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fig]

```
%% Construct polar grid (put inside another function)

range = 0.2:0.2:1;
n = 50;

for i=1:length(range)

    ro = ones(1,n);
    ro = ro.*range(i);

    th = linspace(0,pi*2,n);

    [xx,yy] = pol2cart(th,ro);
    plot(xx,yy, 'color',[.9 .9 .9]), grid on, hold on

    n = round(n * 1.5);

end

%% Plot like normal

x1 = [.2 .4 .4 .8];
y1 = [.4 .2 .8 .4];

x2 = [.4 .8];
y2 = [.4 .8];

plot(x1,y1, 'bx',...
     x2,y2, 'ro');

xlim([-.05 1]);
ylim([-.05 1]);
```

Comment: What you do with `n` is strange. As the perimeter is proportional to the radius, you should multiply by the ratio of the radii instead.